# Error building SIMULTE in OMNET++ 5.0 with INET 3.4

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm encountering the following error when trying to build simuLTE over the right versions of OMNET++ and INET (the versions specified in simulte web). The error is the following:

```
    Cannot parse /simulte-1.0.0/.oppbuildspec
  /simulte-1.0.0/.oppbuildspec: unrecognized option: --meta:export-include-path
  /simulte-1.0.0/.oppbuildspec: unrecognized option: --meta:export-include-path
```

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was building simulte from Omnet Gui i.e. right clicking on simulte project and then Build project.

It was resolved when I built it with terminal (im using ubuntu). So,

1. Open a terminal.
2. Go to simulte directory in your workspace.
3. Run "make clean".
4. Run "make makefiles".
5. Run "make".

Doing this resolved my error. I hope it will resolve yours too..